# Como forçar sessão com o Android?

Tags: java, android, session

Estou com dificuldade ao desenvolver uma parte do meu aplicativo. Vamos lá. Primeiramente preciso clicar em um botão e acessar um determinado link e então a aplicação me retornar um PDF.

Isso já existe por meio do navegador.

O link é esse por exemplo: https://portal.ufac.br/aluno/aluno/relatorio/atestadoMatricula.action?matricula=123456

O problema é que para eu poder acessar esse valida com a sessão, pra ver se o usuário está realmente logado.

Então como posso fazer para forçar um login nesta página: https://portal.ufac.br/aluno/

E então poder acessar o link de download normalmente? Obrigado!

Comment: Este portal possui alguma API?

Comment: Provavelmente não. =(

Comment: Você pode criar um `BroadcastReceiver` com o `IntentFilter` `android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` e, ao completar o download do PDF que você precisa, execute alguma ação em sua `Activity`

Comment: Vou tentar. Mas assim, o problema, pelo menos na WEB, é que se eu acessar o link do download sem estar logado no portal ele retorna para a página de login.

Comment: Se não tiver uma API que você consiga autenticar o usuário, vai ficar impossível você conseguir navegar no site... O usuário irá ter que se logar e fazer toda a navegação na `WebView`